# How to get plot1 and plot2 values

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Times are stored in an `MSMutableArray`. How to get values of `Plot 1` and `Plot 2` in a single statement?

```
{
"11:24:53 AM" =     {
    "Plot 1" = "4.883";
    "Plot 2" = "0.293";
};
"11:30:18 AM" =     {
    "Plot 1" = "4.883";
    "Plot 2" = "0.293";
};
"11:31:28 AM" =     {
    "Plot 1" = "4.883";
    "Plot 2" = "0.293";
};
"11:34:04 AM" =     {
    "Plot 1" = "4.883";
    "Plot 2" = "0.293";
};
"11:36:05 AM" =     {
    "Plot 1" = "4.883";
    "Plot 2" = "0.293";
};
```

}

Comment: Is it JSON? Your array seems to be filled with a `NSDictionary` (with Key of type "XX:XX:XX XM") of NSDictionary (with key "Plot 1" and "Plot 2").

Comment: Let us know the desired output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by using

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];

for(int i = 0; i < keys.count; i ++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@", [[dic objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] objectForKey:@"Plot 1"]);
  NSLog(@"%@", [[dic objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] objectForKey:@"Plot 2"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example You had NSDictionary name:test  Try this code

```
for (NSDictionary * plot in [test allValues]) {
        double plot1 = [[plot objectForKey:@"Plot 1"] doubleValue];
        double plot2 = [[plot objectForKey:@"Plot 2"] doubleValue];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
            NSDictionary *externaldict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

            NSArray *array=[externaldict objectForKey:@"yourkeynamename"];

            for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
            {
                NSDictionary *subdict=[array objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString *plot1String=[subdict objectForKey:@"plot1"];

                NSString *plot2String=[subdict objectForKey:@"plot2"];

                NSString *combinedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",plot1String,plot2String];

                NSLog(@"Final String is:%@",combinedString);
            }
```

I don't know it helps you are not..But check it..

Answer (score 0):

You can get Plot1 values using this [array valueForKey:@"Plot 1"]

For Plot2, its [array valueForKey:@"Plot 2"]